# Spring Integration : FTP Outbound Gateway File Move & Get

Tags: spring-integration

My requirement is to download the file from FTP (ex : FTP Dir "A") do validation and do some process. once processed , the same file has to moved "A" to FTP Dir "B".

Tried below once

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "jsonHttpOutBoundChannel",outputChannel = "testChannel")
    public void handler() {
        FtpOutboundGateway ftpOutboundGateway = new FtpOutboundGateway(ftpSessionFactory.getFTPSessionFactory(), "mv");
        Message message1 = MessageBuilder.withPayload(false)
                .setHeader("file_renameTo", "/FTP/success")
                .setHeader("file_remoteFile", "category.xml")
                .setHeader("file_remoteDirectory","/FTP/process")
                .build();
        ftpOutboundGateway.handleMessage(message1);
    }
```

getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.getRemoteFilename(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.doMv(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:629)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:526)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at au.com.fluentretail.ftp.integration.serviceactivators.FTPServiceActivator.handler(FTPServiceActivator.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:129)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:347).
```

Tried with RemoteFileTemplate with AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway ,

```
@Bean
   @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "jsonHttpOutBoundChannel")
   public MessageHandler gatewayHandler() throws IOException {    

       Expression expression = new LiteralExpression("/processing");
       Expression fileExpression = new LiteralExpression("category.xml");
       RemoteFileTemplate remoteFileTemplate = new RemoteFileTemplate(ftpSessionFactory.getFTPSessionFactory());
       remoteFileTemplate.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(expression);
       remoteFileTemplate.setFileNameExpression(fileExpression);

       AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway ftpOutboundGateway = new FtpOutboundGateway(remoteFileTemplate, "get");
       ftpOutboundGateway.setLocalDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(CONSTANTS.ftpErrorPath));

       ftpOutboundGateway.setRequiresReply(false);
       return ftpOutboundGateway;
   }
```

still facing the same issue.

```
2017-09-14 15:55:25.058 ERROR 14648 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [gatewayHandler]; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=, headers={file_renameTo=/success, file_originalFile=/processing/category.xml, id=68fd370f-eb77-66a5-3462-e8f50c0c068c, file_remoteDirectory=/processing, file_remoteFile=category.xml, timestamp=1505384725042}]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:236)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:185)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:236)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:185)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.splitter.AbstractMessageSplitter.produceOutput(AbstractMessageSplitter.java:159)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:236)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:185)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:236)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:185)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:210)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.getRemoteFilename(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.doGet(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:564)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:520)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    ... 81 more
```

It seems common issue there and here.

Can some one help me please.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** : `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BeanFactory must not be null` is thrown on below code , it is already a bean. 
This exception is thrown even if `sessionFactory` is used instead of `RemoteFileTemplate`

```
@Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "finalProcessChannel")
    public MessageHandler finalProcessHandler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                String fileName = message.getHeaders().get("file_name").toString();
                message = MessageBuilder.createMessage("",createHeaders(message,CONSTANTS.ftpProcessingPath,CONSTANTS.ftpSuccessPath));
                RemoteFileTemplate fileTemplate = new RemoteFileTemplate(ftpSessionFactory.getFTPSessionFactory());
                FtpOutboundGateway ftpOutboundGateway = new FtpOutboundGateway(fileTemplate, "mv","'"+CONSTANTS.ftpProcessingPath+"/"+fileName+"'");
                ftpOutboundGateway.setOutputChannelName("outputChannel");
                ftpOutboundGateway.handleMessage(message);
            }
        };
    }
```

**EDIT** : To return `FtpOutboundGateway` i need the file name from Message Header/String for the contructor initialization with expression. And with @Bean if Message is passed as parameter getting `required a bean of type 'org.springframework.messaging.Message' that could not be found` or `required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found`

Ex :

```
  @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "finalProcessChannel")
    public FtpOutboundGateway finalProcessHandler(Message message) {
        String fileName = message.getHeaders().get("file_name").toString();
        return new FtpOutboundGateway(ftpSessionFactory.getFTPSessionFactory(), "mv", "'" + CONSTANTS.ftpProcessingPath + fileName + "'") {
            @Override
            protected Object handleRequestMessage(Message<?> requestMessage) {
                requestMessage = MessageBuilder.createMessage("", createHeaders(requestMessage, CONSTANTS.ftpProcessingPath, CONSTANTS.ftpSuccessPath));
                setOutputChannelName("outputChannel");
                return super.handleRequestMessage(requestMessage);
            }
        };
    }
```

EDIT : with dynamic expression

```
@Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "finalProcessChannel")
    public FtpOutboundGateway finalProcessHandler() {
        return new FtpOutboundGateway(ftpSessionFactory.getFTPSessionFactory(), "mv","'"+CONSTANTS.ftpProcessingPath+"/"+"headers['file_name']"+"'"){
            @Override
            protected Object handleRequestMessage(Message<?> requestMessage) {
                requestMessage = MessageBuilder.createMessage("", createHeaders(requestMessage, CONSTANTS.ftpProcessingPath, CONSTANTS.ftpSuccessPath));
                setOutputChannelName("outputChannel");
                return super.handleRequestMessage(requestMessage);
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the gateway correctly; you shouldn't create a new gateway for each request.

The gateway must be a @Bean so that the framework initializes it correctly.

```
@ServiceActivator(...)
@Bean
public FtpOutboundGateway gateway() {
    ...
}
```

Then send a message to the service's `inputChannel`.

**EDIT**

We should protect against the NPE but the problem is that constructor (in your second example) sets the remote file path expression (with the gateway). Using that constructor you need to add the expression again...

```
        AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway ftpOutboundGateway = new FtpOutboundGateway(remoteFileTemplate, "get", "/processing/category.xml");
```

I would stay away from the constructors that take a `RemoteFileTemplate`; use the ones with a session factory instead.

I will open a JIRA issue for these problems.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Gary. i tried the same in my second example given above. is that the way you are talking about? i

Comment: Thanks @Gary. it worked with new FtpOutboundGateway(remoteFileTemplate, "get", "/processing/category.xml")

Comment: Used session factory one :  **`new FtpOutboundGateway(ftpSessionFactory.getFTPSessionFactory(), "mv","'"+CONSTANTS.ftpProcessingPath+"/"+fileName+"'");`** getting the        `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BeanFactory must not be null
 at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134)
 at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.<init>(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:76)
 at`

Comment: t gives the same error even with `new FtpOutboundGateway(remoteFileTemplate, "get", "/processing/category.xml");`. but the file is getting moved , and it is stopping the flow there because of the exception , not polling any more neither any process after this exception

Comment: Don't put code in comments; its virtually unreadable; edit the question and add a comment to say you've done so. As I said in the answer, the first one is incorrect; the gateway must be a `@Bean` so that it is initialized properly.

Comment: Thanks for the adivce @Gary. see the edit to my question , it is already a Bean. still getting beanfactory null.

Comment: `return new MessageHandler()` - you are wrapping the gateway in your own handler bean so it is NOT a bean; just return the gateway.

Comment: You can't pass a message in like that - `@Bean`s are statically created. You need to use a dynamic expression `return new FtpOutboundGateway(ftpSessionFactory.getFTPSessionFactory(), "mv", "'" + CONSTANTS.ftpProcessingPath + "'" + headers['file_name']");`

Comment: Above one is not working , tried different combinations. getting `After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'file_name' ` @Gary

Comment: EDIT the question again to show your current version.

Comment: see the EDIT to my question @Gary

Comment: Try `"'" + CONSTANTS.ftpProcessingPath +"/' + headers['file_name']"` - you have a literal part + a dynamic part - `' ... ' + headers['file_name']`.

Comment: However, you are over complicating things; you can use a simple adapter with a different expression using those constants and the input message. Also, you should not be setting the `outputChannel` on every request.

Comment: it is evaluating to `null` now. `'/processing/null'`. i could see the `file_name` in headers :   `headers={sequenceNumber=2, file_name=product.xml, sequenceSize=2, correlationId=04f018c9-243b-1a65-9156-b1f291a302cc, file_originalFile=D:\Work\Fluent\FTP\processing\product.xml, id=9e98307b-c8fd-a988-6a01-96e056b0c2ad, timestamp=1505740368751}]`  @Gary

Comment: You don't show your `createMessage()`. Are you still using `file_remoteFile`? In that case the expression needs to use that header instead of `file_name` but, as I said, it would be better to use a simple gateway and set the `renameExpression` property.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gary. Yes. i was using `file_remoteFile` in the `createMessage`. it works after changing from  `file_name` to `file_remoteFile`. I will try to achieve the same with simple gateway as you mentioned. thanks again.